# Kivy color parser invalid colour format

Tags: python, kivy

Hi i have the following codes
main.py

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window


class SpendApp(App):
    pass
if __name__ == '__main__':
   Window.fullscreen = False
   SpendApp().run()
```

spend.kv

```
FloatLayout:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: .1,.4,.5,1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    Label:
        text: '[color= #007f7fff]SET REMINDER[/color] NOW'
        font_name: 'FreeSans'
        font_size: 25
        text_size: self.size
        markup: True
        halign: 'left'
        valign: 'middle'
        size_hint: .5, .2
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
```

I use kivy with python 2.7.9. I want the label to be displayed and the text color formated like i set in the markup 
    text: '[color= #007f7fff]SET REMINDER[/color] NOW'
But when i run the code, i get the warning "invalid color format for u' #007f7fff'", and the the text in the markup brackets are black.
So id like to ask what im doing wrong, and how to get it right.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to set an rgba colour? I think this syntax may only allow rgb.

Comment: How can I use it here? I tried using [color = (3,.7,.9)]  and I still get the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BBCode parser is very strict, no extra spaces are allowed. Your code works if you use

```
text: '[color=#007f7fff]SET REMINDER[/color] NOW'
```

or, for that matter,

```
text: '[color=rgba(0,127,127,255)]SET REMINDER[/color] NOW'
```

The relevant lines in [`kivy.core.text.markup.py` are 194ff](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/core/text/markup.py#L194), this shows how the color string is split and sent to the color parser. And [`kivy.parser.py` l. 38ff](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/parser.py#L38) contains the `parse_color` function, which shows exactly the expected format for color strings.